# how to set valid host and domain names in ubuntu 12.04 to avoid Java exceptions?

Tags: hadoop

How could I set a valid host name to avoid this exception

```
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Invalid host name: local host is: (unknown); destination host is: ""fatima-HP-ProBook-4520s":8042; java.net.UnknownHostException;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is a single node installation

you need hostname to IP mapping for localhost , something like below in your /etc/hosts

`127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain  fatima-HP-ProBook-4520s
 127.0.1.1 fatima-HP-ProBook-4520s`